# How I can show the user-names for a People or Group site column which allow multiple selection inside our PowerBi report

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerbi

I have a SharePoint online list which contain 2 site columns:-

1. People or Group site column which allow multiple selection
2. People or Group site column which allow single selection

and i am showing the above SharePoint list inside PowerBI. where i got the following:-

1. For the "People or Group site column which allow multiple selection" >> i got a list instead of the actual usernames
2. For the "People or Group site column which allow single selection" >> i got the user id instead of the actual username

for point-2 i join the list with the User Information list and i am able to show the username instead of the user ID. but for point-1 i am not sure how i can convert the List into usernames? is this supported?

Answer (score 0):

After you have added the List into Power BI use Power Query Editor (the ellipses on the table and then select edit query) and find the column in question.

As you see below there is a MemberId Column in my example which contains a List value.

[image]

Select the Double Arrows and then select Expand to New Rows.
[image]

You should see a result where each member of the group gets their own row in the table.

[image]

It will come out with the User ID but you should be able to link this the same as you did with point 1.